# ASP.NET Razor with JavaScript 'less than' symbol (<) can't be parsed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I am trying to combine some javascript with server-side variable.

Here I'm trying to replace the "<" sign with the actual less than sign:

```
@{
  string age = '&lt;1'; // assume I got it from the QueryString 
  <text>$('#select1').val('@age'.replace('&lt;','<'));</text> // and when the parser sees the '<' symbol it thinks I'm trying to close the <text> tage
}
```

Is there any way that symbol can be escaped/ignored?

Comment: I would save the "age" in a js variable and do that replacement outside the razor code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Note, it does have to be between script tags for it to work.. (I'm assuming this is the case though)

```
<script>
@{
  string age = '&lt;1'; // assume I got it from the QueryString 
  @: $('#select1').val('@age'.replace('&lt;','<')); // and when the parser sees the '<' symbol it thinks I'm trying to close the <text> tage
}
</script>
```

Update

Incidently, the text syntax you used above will also work (instead of @:).. specifically what is causing the problem in your example is not the < in the javascript, rather the second

```
<text>
```

in the comment

Comment: remember that this only works with [Razor v2](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/) :)

Comment: oh, no. I added the comment already here. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using @(Html.Raw("<"))

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{
      string age = '&lt;1'; // assume I got it from the QueryString 
      <text>var LESS_THAN_CHARCODE = 60;</text> // equivalent for the special character '<' (less than symbol)
      <text>$('#select1').val("@age".replace('&lt;',String.fromCharCode(LESS_THAN_CHARCODE)))</text>
    }
```

For some reason neither `unescape` nor `decodeURIComponent` work for me, but `String.fromCharCode` worked beautifully, considering that '<' will be the only character that needs to be replaced.

Thanks for your help!